# Logging Into New Sandbox That Was Copied From Other Sandbox

Tags: sandbox

I created a new sandbox "SB2" that's copied from another sandbox "SB1". However I cannot figure out the username/password in order to log into this new sandbox "SB2".

What I know and have tried

1. My production username is user@production.com.company
2. My username for sandbox SB1 is user@production.com.company.SB1
3. The email I received when the SB2 sandbox was created indicates that my username is user@production.com.company.SB1.SB2

> Dear Sandbox administrator,
>
> Your new sandbox "SB2" is ready for use. Click https://mydomain--SB2.instance.my.salesforce.com/?un=user%40production.com.company.SB1.SB2 to log in now.

4. Have tried combinations of the user@production.com.company.SB1.SB2 with the passwords for both my production and SB1 usernames
5. Attempted to login at test.salesforce.com, instance.salesforce.com,
   my-domain.salesforce.com
6. I can log in as expected to both Production and SB1
7. I can log into other new sandboxes that were copied from Production using the expected . appended to the username with the same password as Production
8. The forgot my password process does not work because when new sandboxes are created the email address of users is modified.

What's the magic combination for username/password when a new sandbox is copied from another sandbox?

Comment: Is it only with you or other users are also not able to log in? Also have you recieved a mail when refresh was completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the link that's included in the email you receive when SB2 is created shows that your username is user@production.com.company.SB1.SB2, your username actually is user@production.com.company.SB2.

When a sandbox is copied from another sandbox, your username for that new sandbox is still your ***production*** username + the name of the new sandbox.